# Ruby: Confused about how to make sense of this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm a little confused about one part of this code. In line 7 I have commented below.

```
01:states_file = File.open("states_abbrev.txt")
02:states = {}
03:while ! states_file.eof?
04:     first = states_file.gets.chomp
05:     #"ALABAMA,AL"
06:     data = first.split(",")
07:     states[ data[0] ] = data[1] #This line here.
08:end
09:puts states.inspect
10:
11:states_file.close
```

Line 5 is and example of what each line is like in the states_abbrev.txt file. Just a state, a comma, abbreviation, and a carriage return. All 50 states are in the file.

As you can see on line 7 the **data[0]** key seems to be overwritten by **data[1]**. So why is it when i run this code **data[0]** is still the key, and **data[1]** becomes the value?

Answer (score 1):

After line 6

data[0] is ALABAMA, data[1] is AL

After line 7

states is { 'ALABAMA' => 'AL' }

Its not overwriting data[0].. data[0] is the key and data[1] is the value.

One good thing you can try is ruby's irb

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the `data[0]` that is overwritten by `data[1]`. It is the hash `states` that is set `data[1]` (which is a state's name) for the key `data[0]` (which is the abbreviation part of the line).

Perhaps it is easier to understand when you introduce more variables or use better names:

```
file   = File.open("states_abbrev.txt")
states = {}

while !file.eof?
  line = file.gets.chomp
  name, abbr = line.split(",")
  states[abbr] = name
end

file.close
```

Btw: I would probably write something like this:

```
File.open('states_abbrev.txt') do |file|
  file.each_line.map { |line| line.chomp.split(',').reverse }.to_h
end
```

Comment: I had a hard time wrapping my head around it. Now I think I've gotten the concept. Thanks.